# How can i subscribe to multiple observables in angular2 at once and wait, if there is new data on each of them?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

i have a angular component, that uses 3 services. Each of those services has an observer, that i can subscribe to. The view of the component must be updated, if anything on the observed changes, that happens through websockets (feathers.js).
I want the `doSomethingWithTheNewDataThatIsShownOnView()` to be called only once on ngInit and i think, i can do this with forkJoin:

```
private ngOnInit(): void {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.filesService.inputs$,
        this.filesService.outputs$,
        this.processesService.items$
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.inputs = data[0];
          this.outputs = data[1];
          this.processes = data[2];
          this.doSomethingWithTheNewDataThatIsShownOnView();
          this.ref.markForCheck();
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );

    this.filesService.find();
    this.processesService.find();
}
```

That works as expected, but if there is new data on inputs$ Observable or outputs$ Observable, the subscribe is not beeing called again. It is only called, if all three Observables have new data. Is there something like "wait for a interval of 100ms if all three observables have new data, if not use only the new data of all observables, that have new data until now?"

I hope you understand, what i want to do :D

Greets

Chris

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`combineLatest()` should do the trick:

```
private ngOnInit(): void {
    Observable.combineLatest(
        this.filesService.inputs$,
        this.filesService.outputs$,
        this.processesService.items$
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.inputs = data[0];
          this.outputs = data[1];
          this.processes = data[2];
          this.doSomethingWithTheNewDataThatIsShownOnView();
          this.ref.markForCheck();
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );

    this.filesService.find();
    this.processesService.find();
}
```

---

Additional hints on your code:

As an alternative `combineLatest()` also takes an optional aggregation-method and also as a side-note: try to use pure functions only and avoid stateful components(`this.inputs`, `this.outputs`, ect..) and use the `| async` pipe in the template and try to avoid too much logic in the subscription and if possible try to avoid manual subscriptions at all, because those have to be manually unsubscribed but the `async`-pipe could handle that automatically for you:

```
autoUpdatedViewData$ = Observable.combineLatest(
        this.filesService.inputs$,
        this.filesService.outputs$,
        this.processesService.items$,
        (inputs, outputs, items) => ({inputs, outputs, items})
    )
    .map(({inputs, outputs, items}) => {
        return this.doSomethingWithTheNewDataThatIsShownOnView(inputs, outputs, items);
    });

private ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filesService.find();
    this.processesService.find();
}

// in your template
<div>{{autoUpdatedViewData$ | async}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints and your working solution!! I will have to refactor a lot of code to avoid stateful components but i can see the benefit. Greetings, Chris

Comment: thanks dude combineLatest() did my job, i don't know why same code was not working with forkJoin

Comment: 'Observable.combineLatest' is deprecated