# After posted or updated the data then navigating to home not fetching the last data

Tags: angular

```
constructor(private pokedexApi:ApiPokemonsService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPokemons()
}

// instead of pokemon having an Id of the pokedex, is better to retrieve the data of that id to the pokemon attribute
getPokemons() {
 
  // subscribing Api data from the this method
  this.pokedexApi.getPokemons().subscribe(data => {
      // this.isLoading = true
      this.data = data;
      // console.log("from the details")
      // instead of 
      for (let pokemon of this.data) {
        // this.isLoading = true
        let id = pokemon.pokedexData;
        // console.log(typeof(id))
        this.pokedexApi.getPokedex(Number(id)).subscribe(data => {
          // this.isLoading = false
          pokemon.pokedexData = data;
        });
      }
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
 
}
```

When I create or update the data in another component. This home fetching data not syncing, just I have to click a *nav* links, then correctly fetching all the data.

And the navigating to home after updated or created not refreshing the data
(correctly everything is working just after updated to see last data I have to click one of links of the page).

What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate if someone help this, this took all my time.

```
this.apiPokemons.addPokemon(this.user).subscribe(data=> {
        this.toast.open('successfully added new Pokemon');
      });
this.router.navigate([`${'/pokemons'}`])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wait for `addPokemon` method to be completed:

move your redirect inside `subscribe`:

```
this.apiPokemons.addPokemon(this.user).subscribe(data=>{
    this.toast.open('successfully added new Pokemon');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/pokemons');
});
```

Comment: thanks worked, so every time I have to wait untill the subscription finishing. what if I create a method after this àddPokemon` how I have to wait untill finishing the subscribe

Comment: then you can use pipe() with map operators, or forkJoin() to merge multiple observables. one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060371/how-can-i-subscribe-to-multiple-observables-in-angular2-at-once-and-wait-if-the