# how to handle same value from multiple datastreams in Angular RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have two different data streams which gives same object with modified property values. I want to write a single subscription so that whenever any of the two DataStream notifies about property modification I can reuse the same code.

```
const selectedItems$ = this.grid.onSelect.pipe(.... this gives me the selected object);
const updatedItem$ = this.fetchData.onUpdate.pipe(.....this gives me the updated object);

displayItem$(selection$, updatedItem$) {
   (..here i want to get notified whenever there is change in).subscribe(item => {
       this.displayLatest(item)
   })
}
```

selectedItem$ and updatedItem$ can return same object with different property values when the already selected item is modified.

This is the first time I am working on RxJs and bit confused about this part. I searched in RxJS operators list (like concat, merge, combine) but most of the working examples are for different data structures. Also is there any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060371/how-can-i-subscribe-to-multiple-observables-in-angular2-at-once-and-wait-if-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge` to create an observable that emits values from both source streams:

```js
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

...

merge(selection$, updatedItem$)
  .subscribe(item => {
    this.displayLatest(item)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve Holgado. It worked for me.